# MvvmCross : Empty binding target passed to MvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I created an Android application with Xamarin and MvvmCross.
I want to bind some views (text, editing text, button) to my ViewModel. Nothing strange well so far. But my bindings don’t apply… When I use typed FindViewById, I don’t get the traced error but bindings doesn’t apply.

When I run the application, I have the following trace:

```
MvxBind:Error: Empty binding target passed to MvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry
MvxBind:Warning: Failed to create target binding for binding for TextProperty
```

My override of `OnCreate(Bundle bundle)` void is :

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Reference);
var referenceTextView = FindViewById(Resource.Id.referenceEditView); // untyped FindViewById
var siteTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.siteTextView); // typed FindViewById<T>
//var goButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.goButton);
var bindingsSet = this.CreateBindingSet<ReferenceView, ReferenceViewModel>();
bindingsSet.Bind(referenceTextView).To(vm => vm.Reference).Mode(MvxBindingMode.TwoWay);
bindingsSet.Bind(siteTextView).To(vm => vm.Site);
//bindingsSet.Bind(goButton).To(vm => vm.GoCommand);
bindingsSet.Apply();
base.OnCreate(bundle);
```

I’ve tried to do in the AXML :

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/siteTextView"
    android:text="####"
    local:MvxBind="Text Site"
    android:gravity="center" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/referenceTextView"
    android:hint="Numéro de dossier"
    local:MvxBind="Text Reference" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Accéder"
    android:id="@+id/goButton"
    local:MvxBind="Click GoCommand" />
```

The getters and setters of my properties use RaiseAndSetIfChanged method :

```
private string _reference;
public string Reference
{
    get { return _reference; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _reference, value, () => Reference); }
}
```

I’ve the same `LinkerPleaseInclude` class than [LinkerPleaseInclude](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ApiExamples/ApiExamples.Droid/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs) original class.
My setup inherits from `MvxAndroidSetup` class
And on other ViewModels, the bindings are applied correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `base.OnCreate(bundle);` before `SetContentView` as the ViewModel is located and attached inside of that call. Failing to do so will obviously give you the exact errors you see. Source will be null and will not bind to the target.

So you can either do:

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Reference);
```

And have all your bindings in your AXML. Or you can do the other approach setting the bindings behind the scenes:

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Reference);

var referenceTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.referenceEditView);
var siteTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.siteTextView);

var bset = this.CreateBindingSet<ReferenceView, ReferenceViewModel>();
bset.Bind(referenceTextView).To(vm => vm.Reference);
bset.Bind(siteTextView).To(vm => vm.Site);
bset.Apply();
```

Just make sure to call `base.OnCreate` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The warnings

> MvxBind:Error:  2,20 Empty binding target passed to MvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry
>   MvxBind:Warning:  2,20 Failed to create target binding for binding  for Text

are caused by `var referenceTextView = FindViewById(Resource.Id.referenceEditView);` resulting in `referenceTextView` to be of type `View`.

MvvmCross is searching for the **default binding target** property of the type `TTarget` when calling `Bind<TTArget>` **without** `For(targetProperty)`. This is just a look up in a table like:

```
TTarget       Property
----------------------
TextView      Text
Button        Click
...           ...
```

In your case `TTarget` is `View` instead of `TextView`, because you pass it into `bindingsSet.Bind(referenceTextView)` wich is the implicit call of `bindings.Bind<View>(btnNumber)`. `View` has no default binding target property. You have to set it explicitly like

```
bindings.Bind(btnNumber).For("Text")
```

or use the typed `FindViewById<TextView>`.

Comment: I may have misspoke. I used different approaches I know: I used typed and untyped FindViewById method.

Comment: Ok then to as Cheesebaron said, and move the `base.OnCreate(bundle)` to the top of the function (call it before everything else).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to bind twice, remove these lines:

```
var referenceTextView = FindViewById(Resource.Id.referenceEditView); // untyped FindViewById
var siteTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.siteTextView); // typed FindViewById<T>
//var goButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.goButton);
var bindingsSet = this.CreateBindingSet<ReferenceView, ReferenceViewModel>();
bindingsSet.Bind(referenceTextView).To(vm => vm.Reference).Mode(MvxBindingMode.TwoWay);
bindingsSet.Bind(siteTextView).To(vm => vm.Site);
//bindingsSet.Bind(goButton).To(vm => vm.GoCommand);
bindingsSet.Apply();
```

So your on create is just this:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Reference);
base.OnCreate(bundle);
```

And keep the bindings in the axml file.

**Make sure you have this at the top of your xaml file:**

`xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Also if you are doing bindings in the cs file, the MvvmCross binding mode is TwoWay by default. So you dont need `.Mode(MvxBindingMode.TwoWay);`

Comment: Sure, I may have misspoke: I used different approaches I know. I have the line you specify in my AXML file.

Comment: Ah no worries, generally on Android I tend to do the bindings in the xaml unless it's something unusual.